# excel vba delete rows macro returns "type mismatch"

Tags: vba, excel

My code works perfectly if the selected cell you tell it to delete is filled out with one of the part #'s from the drop down list.

But if you type in a new or custom # then want to delete that part # later the macro returns a

> Type mismatch (Error 13)

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error GoTo whoa

If ActiveCell.Row <= 8 Then
    MsgBox "Ooops!" & vbNewLine & _
    vbNewLine & "Please select a Part Number"
ElseIf MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this part?" & vbNewLine & _
              vbNewLine & _
              ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, "A").Value & vbNewLine & _
              ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, "B").Value & vbNewLine & _
              "QTY: " & ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, "M").Value, _
              vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
   ActiveCell.Resize(3, 1).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
whoa:
    MsgBox "Please select a number from the drop down list" & vbNewLine & _
    "then run the delete command again.", vbInformation, Err.Description
End Sub
```

How can I get rid of that error and still have it delete the 3 rows (each part is 3 rows) if I enter a custom #.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the type mismatch error is occurring on the `.Delete`?

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: Im sure doing something like activeRowVariable.Rows(x:y).Delete should be more than enough to get the job done